Blender Python Script: Geometry Nodes Modifier Parameters Not Applied in Exported GLTF Model
I want to modify the 3 input params of my GeometryNodes modifier of my blender object via a python cmd line script, but the exported model looks like the original one, so the input paramater changes dont get applied to the modifier and I dont know whats the issue in the code.
import bpy
import sys
import argparse

# Get the args after "--"
argv = sys.argv
argv = argv[argv.index("--") + 1:] if "--" in argv else []

def setup_geometry_nodes(params):
    # Access the Geometry Nodes modifier
    geo_modifier = bpy.data.objects["Plane"].modifiers["GeometryNodes"]

    # Update Height
    height_id = geo_modifier.node_group.interface.items_tree["Height"].identifier
    print(f"Setting height id={height_id} to {params['Height']}")
    geo_modifier[height_id] = params['Height']

    # Update Size X
    size_x_id = geo_modifier.node_group.interface.items_tree["Size X"].identifier
    print(f"Setting size_x id={size_x_id} to {params['Size X']}")
    geo_modifier[size_x_id] = params['Size X']

    # Update Size Y
    size_y_id = geo_modifier.node_group.interface.items_tree["Size Y"].identifier
    print(f"Setting size_y id={size_y_id} to {params['Size Y']}")
    geo_modifier[size_y_id] = params['Size Y']

    # Verify changes
    print(f'Height value now = {geo_modifier[height_id]}')
    print(f'Size X value now = {geo_modifier[size_x_id]}')
    print(f'Size Y value now = {geo_modifier[size_y_id]}')

    # Force update the scene and dependency graph
    bpy.context.view_layer.update()
    bpy.context.evaluated_depsgraph_get()

def apply_and_export_model(params):
    # Ensure object is in object mode
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')

    # Update Geometry Nodes parameters
    setup_geometry_nodes({
        'Size X': params['size_x'],
        'Size Y': params['size_y'],
        'Height': params['height'],
    })

    # Select the object and apply the modifier
    obj = bpy.data.objects["Plane"]
    bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = obj
    obj.select_set(True)

    # Apply the Geometry Nodes modifier
    bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply(modifier="GeometryNodes")

    # Force update the scene and dependency graph after applying the modifier
    bpy.context.view_layer.update()
    bpy.context.evaluated_depsgraph_get()

    # Export as GLTF
    bpy.ops.export_scene.gltf(
        filepath=params['output_path'],
        export_format='GLB',
        use_selection=True,
        export_apply=True
    )

if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('--size_x', type=float, default=1.0)
    parser.add_argument('--size_y', type=float, default=1.0)
    parser.add_argument('--height', type=float, default=1.0)
    parser.add_argument('--output_path', type=str, default="//output.glb")
    
    args = parser.parse_args(argv)  # Parse only the args after "--"
    
    export_params = {
        'size_x': args.size_x,
        'size_y': args.size_y,
        'height': args.height,
        'output_path': args.output_path
    }
    
    apply_and_export_model(export_params)

I execute the script like this:
blender -b "Diffuser Model V2.blend" --python render_model.py -- --size_x 1.5 --size_y 1.5 --height 0.7 --output_path output.glb

Output:
Blender 4.2.3 LTS (hash 0e22e4fcea03 built 2024-10-14 23:47:09)
Read blend: "Diffuser Model V2.blend"
Setting height id=Socket_7 to 0.7
Setting size_x id=Socket_4 to 1.5
Setting size_y id=Socket_5 to 1.5
Height value now = 0.699999988079071
Size X value now = 1.5
Size Y value now = 1.5
INFO Draco mesh compression is available, use library at /Applications/Blender.app/Contents/Resources/4.2/python/lib/python3.11/site-packages/libextern_draco.dylib
23:31:29 | INFO: Starting glTF 2.0 export
23:31:29 | INFO: Extracting primitive: Plane
23:31:29 | INFO: Primitives created: 1
23:31:29 | INFO: Finished glTF 2.0 export in 0.002081155776977539 s


Blender quit

